# Fedora Directory Server Installation

Tags: redhat, fedora

I'm new to Fedora Directory Server and tried to install fedora-ds-1.0.4-1.FC6.i386.opt.rpm on my RedHat Linux machine.

During the setup, I selected 'Typical' install mode and encountered the following error:

```
[slapd-localhost]: starting up server ...
[slapd-localhost]:         Fedora-Directory/1.0.4 B2006.312.1539
[slapd-localhost]:         localhost.localdomain:389 (/opt/fedora-ds/slapd-localhost)
[slapd-localhost]: 
[slapd-localhost]: [27/Jan/2012:16:52:16 +0800] - Fedora-Directory/1.0.4 B2006.312.1539 starting up
[slapd-localhost]: [27/Jan/2012:16:52:17 +0800] - slapd started.  Listening on All Interfaces port 389 for LDAP requests
Your new directory server has been started.
Created new Directory Server
Start Slapd Starting Slapd server configuration.
Fatal Slapd ERROR: Ldap authentication failed for url ldap://localhost.localdomain:389/o=NetscapeRoot user id admin (151:Unknown error.)
Fatal Slapd Did not add Directory Server information to Configuration Server.
Configuring Administration Server...
Setting up Administration Server Instance...
ERROR: Administration Server configuration failed.

You can now use the console.  Here is the command to use to start the console:
cd /opt/fedora-ds
./startconsole -u admin -a http://localhost.localdomain:8506/

INFO Finished with setup, logfile is setup/setup.log
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Fedora Directory Server does not exist any more.

It has been renamed 389 Directory Server and the latest version is 1.2.9 which you can grab from their website [here](http://directory.fedoraproject.org/)

As their site says about FDS

> These releases are very old, and provided for historical purposes
>   only.

Comment: The problem is my Linux machine is not connected to internet :(

Comment: Well either connect it to the web or download the relevant rpms to another machine, move them over and install from those.

Comment: Do you have the link to the RPMs of 389 Directory Server?

Comment: here is the Epel mirror list http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/publiclist/EPEL/